# Calls to gateway result never return to caller when successful

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration DSL and have a simple Gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "eventGateway", defaultRequestChannel = "inputChannel")
public interface EventProcessorGateway {
  @Gateway(requestChannel="inputChannel")
  public void processEvent(Message message)
}
```

My spring integration flow is defined as:

```
@Bean MessageChannel inputChannel() { return new DirectChannel(); }

@Bean MessageChannel errorChannel() { return new DirectChannel(); }

@Bean MessageChannel retryGatewayChannel() { return new DirectChannel(); }

@Bean MessageChannel jsonChannel() { return new DirectChannel(); }

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow postEvents() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel())
            .route("headers.contentType", m -> m.channelMapping(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "json")
            )
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow retryGateway() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("json")
        .gateway(retryGatewayChannel(), e -> e.advice(retryAdvice()))
        .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow transformJsonEvents() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(retryGatewayChannel())
            .transform(new JsonTransformer())
            .handle(new JsonHandler())
            .get();
}
```

The JsonTransformer is a simple AbstractTransformer that transforms the JSON data and passes it to the JsonHandler.

```
class JsonHandler extends AbstractMessageHandler {
  public void handleMessageInternal(Message message) throws Exception {
    // do stuff, return nothing if success else throw Exception
  }
}
```

I call my gateway from code as such:

```
try {
  Message<List<EventRecord>> message = MessageBuilder.createMessage(eventList, new MessageHeaders(['contentType': contentType]))
  eventProcessorGateway.processEvent(message)
  logSuccess(eventList)
} catch (Exception e) {
  logError(eventList)
}
```

I want the entire call and processing to be synchronous, and any errors that occur to be caught so I can handle them appropriately.  The call to the gateway works, the message gets sent to through the Transformer and to the Handler, processed and if an Exception occurs it bubbles back and is caught and logError() is called.  However if the call is successful, the call to logSuccess() never occurs.  It is like execution stops/hangs after the Handler processes the message and never returns.  I do not need to actually get any response, I am more concerned if something fails to process.  Do I need to send something back to the initial EventProcessorGateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("json")
    .gateway(retryGatewayChannel(), e -> e.advice(retryAdvice()))
    .get();
```

where that `.gateway()` is `request/reply` because it is a part of the main flow.
It is something similar to the `<gateway>` within `<chain>`.

So, even if your main flow is one-way, using `.gateway()` inside that requires from your sub-flow some reply, but this one:

```
        .handle(new JsonHandler())
        .get();
```

doesn't do that.

Because it is `one-way` `MessageHandler`.

From other side, even if you'd make the last one as `request-reply` (`AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`), it won't help you because you don't know what to do with that reply after the mid-flow `gateway`. Just because your main flow is the `one-way`.

You must re-think your desing a bit more and try to get rid of that mid-flow gateway. I see that you try to make some logic with `retryAdvice()`.
But how about to move it to the `.handle(new JsonHandler())` instead of that wrong `.gateway()`?

Comment: I was using a retryGateway() because I didn't realize I could add Advice directly into the flow.  Now I see I can just add it with the handler as such:

    `@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow transformJsonEvents() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("json")
                .transform(new TestTransformer())
                .handle(new TestHandler(), m -> m.advice(retryAdvice()))
                .get();
    }`

Comment: You can also set `replyTimeout` to 0 on the in-line gateway to release the thread since no reply will be returned. But @Artem's suggestion is better; I am just adding this here for completeness.